# how to get exact text value inside a tag in jquery when entities are used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list inside a anchor tag like this

```
<a href="#" class = "set_priority" data-value = "{{$candidate->id}}" style="text-decoration: none;">
   @if($candidate->priority == "") 
     <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Prioritize</li></a><br>
   @elseif($candidate->priority == "yes")
     <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Deprioritize</li></a><br>
   @endif
```

I have used entity &nbsp for styling purpose. The above code generate html tag according to the response from the server. So it might look either one of these

```
<li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Prioritize</li>
<li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Deprioritize</li>
```

I want to alert something when the list item is clicked. I don't know how to compare when `&nbsp` is used

```
$('.set_priority').on('click',function(){

    var priority_value = $(this).first().text();
    if (priority_value = "Prioritize") {
        alert('he Prioritised');
    }

    else if (priority_value = "Deprioritize") {
        alert('Prioritised');
    }


});
```

It always alerts `alert('he Prioritised');` whatever may be the condition.

Comment: `priority_value == "DePrioritize"` when 1 = it means initialize when 2 checking if same/equal. use `== / ===` to check if equal same. use `=` to initialize

Comment: `if (priority_value = "Prioritize") {` still same

Comment: apart from your question, why not use inline css instead of that `&nbsp;`

Comment: or not-inline CSS. Really any CSS is better than `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use comparison operator instead assignment operator and use *trim* method to remove spaces.

```
$('.set_priority').on('click',function(){

    var priority_value = $(this).first().text().trim();
    if (priority_value == "Prioritize") {
        alert('he Prioritised');
    }

    else if (priority_value == "Deprioritize") {
        alert('Prioritised');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace &nbsp with empty in temporary variable, then compare it. like:-

```
 var priority_value = $(this).first().text();
 var temp = priority_value.replace(/&nbsp;/gi,'');
    if (temp == "DePrioritize") {
        alert('he Prioritised');
    }

    else if (temp == "Deprioritize") {
        alert('Prioritised');
    }
```

Comment: `temp = "DePrioritize"` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the `click` handler like this

```
$('set_property li').on('click', function(){
  var priority = $(this).first().text(); // This will give you the actual clicked element
  // .... rest is same
});
```

Comment: nothing to do with the click everything to do with the if statement